# Strange behaviour of Regexp_replace in a Hive SQL query

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

I have some input information where I'm trying to remove the part `.0` from my input where an ID string ends with `.0`.

`select student_id, regexp_replace(student_id, '.0','') from school_result.credit_records where student_id like '%.0';`

Input:

```
01-0230984.03
12345098.0
34567.0
```

Expected output:

```
01-0230984.03 
12345098
34567
```

But the result I'm getting is as follows: It's removing any character having with a `0` next to it instead of removing only the occurrences that end with `.0`

```
0129843
123498
34567
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Dot in regexp](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) has special meaning (it means any character). If you need dot (.) literally, it should be shielded using double-slash (in Hive). Also add end-of-the-line anchor($):

```
with mydata as (
select stack(3,
'01-0230984.03',
'12345098.0',
'34567.0'
) as str
)

select regexp_replace(str,'\\.0$','') from mydata;
```

Result:

```
01-0230984.03
12345098
34567
```

Regexp `'\\.0$'` means dot zero (`.0`) literally, end of the line (`$`).

Comment: Just wanted to know: If I want to specify something to be removed at the beginning of the line instead of the end, then what should I specify in place of `$` ??

Comment: @LearneR beginning anchor is `^`  Like this: '^0' - means zero at the beginning