# Hive - Regex for the SYSLOG/ERRORLOG

Tags: regex, hive, create-table, amazon-athena, regexserde

I want to query the syslog(basically its my SQL error log) using Athena. here is my sample data.

```
2019-09-21T12:19:32.107Z 2019-09-21 12:19:24.17 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary. 

2019-09-21T12:19:32.107Z 2019-09-21 12:19:24.29 Server      InitializeExternalUserGroupSid failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
```

So I created a table like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bhuvi (
  timestamp string,
  date string,
  time string,
  user string,
  message stringg
 ) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
 "input.regex" = "(\\w+)\\s+(.*\\-.*\\-.*)\\s+(\\d+:\\d+:\\d+.\\d+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)"
 ) LOCATION 's3://log/sql_error_log_stream/';
```

But it didn't give any results. Can someone help me to figure it out?

Comment: check the field delimiter and try specifying it in `FIELDS TERMINATED BY`

Comment: Im not sure fields terminated by as option for Regex serde.

Comment: Also there is a typo in stringg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few observations:

1. Timestamp `'2019-09-21T12:19:32.107Z'` is not in hive `TIMESTAMP` format, define it as `STRING` in DDL and convert like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23520257/2700344
2. message in the serde is represented as (\w+) group. This is wrong because message contains spaces. Try `(.*?)$` instead of `(\\w+)` for message field.

   Try this regexp:

   `(\\S+)\\s+(.*-.*-.*)\\s+(\\d+:\\d+:\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(.*?)$`

Use `(\\S+)` - this means everything except spaces. 
`(\\w+)` does not work for the first group because `\\w` matches any alphanumerical character and the underscore only, and first group (timestamp) contains `-` and `:` characters also.

Also hyphen `-` if outside of character class [in square brackets] does not need shielding. and Dot . has a special meaning and needs shielding when used as dot literally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890202/2700344

Comment: I tried it. `"input.regex" = "(\\w+)\\s+(.*\\-.*\\-.*)\\s+(\\d+:\\d+:\\d+.\\d+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(.*?)$"` but no results. :(

Comment: @Bhuvanesh please check my regexp