# which is the most optimal way to filter out string column in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, query-optimization, hiveql, where-clause

I am filtering on a string column called mycolumn. I can think of the following 3 ways to filter, which will be achieve better performance ?

```
-- method #1
where
(   mycolumn = 'FixedStringA.FixedStringB.VariableStringA.FixedString' 
OR mycolumn = 'FixedStringA.FixedStringB.VariableStringB.FixedString' 
OR mycolumn = 'FixedStringA.FixedStringB.VariableStringC.FixedString' 
OR mycolumn = 'FixedStringA.FixedStringB.VariableStringD.FixedString' );

-- method #2
where mycolumn like '%//.FixedString';

-- method #3
where split(mycolumn,'//.')[3] = 'FixedString';
```

Please know that FixedStringA and FixedStringB are like constants , their values will remain fixed, that's why calling them fixed strings. And mycolumn is not a partition key for your info.

Comment: I suggest method #1 if your filter  is static all the time, which save time/performance for you. Or if you have situation where you need to change your filter condition it is good to go with method #2 & method #3 which are a kind of regex type.

Answer (score 0):

In the method 3 it should be `\\.` not `//.` See this answer: [Dot in regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57890202/2700344)

Also in the method 2 it is probably should be  `like '%.FixedString'`

Also you can use rlike:

```
RLIKE '\\.FixedString$'
```

You will not notice the difference in Hive because it is full-scan anyway and it is running in parallel.

I'd prefer `RLIKE '\\.FixedString$'` because it is short and powerful regexp-like.

splitting and producing array (method 3) will create more pressure on memory and garbage collector, you will create and free much more objects.

method 1 is also good, but looks not so elegant. Method 1 can be better if you have internal indexes like in ORC file, you need to check it yourself.